# 3rd level nav controller crashes when trying to connect any outlet

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iboutlet

I have a table view nav controller that once a cell is selected it loads to a details view and then another button that leads to a sub details view. Whenever i try add anything to the third level nav view it crashes, be it a label, image, anything, even just `image.hidden=YES;` crashes? any ideas why?

Comment: if you dont add any thing on third view then it is not crashing ?

Comment: I strongly suspect the reason is in your code which you haven't posted here.

Comment: it will navigate to the view but when I try and add any outlet to a label or anything else then it just crashes, it's fidly to explain sorry

Comment: i am agree with Praveen that may be some problem with your code..it may be a chance where you are allocating a controller and releasing when it is in use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
ThirdController *thirdController = [[ThirdController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdController animated:YES];
[thirdController release];
```

Comment: I had a capital by mistake. just changed MapViewController to mapViewController. Simple problem, thanks!